# Codeigniter implement cache support

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, memcached

I hope somebody has some experience with cache/memcached feature in codeigniter. I have just installed in my vps server `memcached` and `php5-memcached` and now I really need to use it inside my code.

How my website works:

- I am using flickr, google maps and youtube api and I need to cache
  search results because sometime the search result's page load time
  gets even up to **15s** wich is very much.

I've just configured `$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;` to **TRUE** and load time has decreased but not enough.

So, how can I cache the search results the apis I use?

Edit: 
not 15ms, but 15s to load the page

Comment: 15ms is not too much if you are mentioning the whole duration for page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample workflow that might work for you:

- Fetch the data from the API's
- Serialize the response:  `$data = serialize("api response");`
- Save the serialized data to memcached and set an expiration limit
- On each subsequent request, fetch the data from memcache and `unserialize();` it

References:

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php